# What determines the optimal height of embedded plaintext files?

Tags: html, css, webkit

I've run into an odd issue when embedding plaintext files in html [here](https://smaslennikov.com/haikus). These plaintext files range in their number of lines, and I used to determine the optimal height of the field with a simple multiplication, with a ratio of 22.

Turns out, the larger the number of lines, the less this works. I've put together this table to describe how the ratio and slope change, based on four data points (the optimal height is defined by that which doesn't generate a scrollbar):

```
3          66               22         N/A
9          186              20.66      20.00
23         366              15.913     12.87
33         516              15.636     15.00
```

You can also see the odd graph [here](https://smaslennikov.com/assets/in_emergency/rhymes_graph.png). Currently, I [use this equation](https://github.com/smaslennikov/smaslennikov.github.io/blob/master/bin/build_haikus.sh#L15) to calculate the embed heights. This won't work well for all numbers of lines, however.

I don't understand why:

1. This isn't a linear fit, considering the font is monospaced, and
2. The slope changes with each datapoint